# Slack not starting after update

Tags: apt, slack

I encountered an issue where, after a routine `apt-get upgrade`, `slack` i.e. `slack-desktop` refused to open, with no real indication why from the logs.

After trying most of the solutions from [this older post](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=&ved=2ahUKEwjI_f6zl9X4AhUaHcAKHW2YAm0QFnoECA8QAQ&url=https%3A%2F%2Faskubuntu.com%2Fquestions%2F1257336%2Fslack-suddenly-stopped-working-on-ubuntu-20-04&usg=AOvVaw18bYhKE_YCzajqcxpspA_T) I ended update manually downloading the deb as indicated in my answer below....

FYI version 4.27.154 caused the failure to start.

Answer (score 0):

In my search for an older version to roll back to, I ended up scouring the [flathub code](https://github.com/flathub/com.slack.Slack/blob/master/com.slack.Slack.json) for a url for downloading an older .deb and came across:

`https://downloads.slack-edge.com/releases/linux/$version/prod/x64/slack-desktop-$version-amd64.deb`

Replacing the $version with a version number found on [the slack release notes page](https://slack.com/release-notes/linux) did the trick.

Example:

```
wget https://downloads.slack-edge.com/releases/linux/4.26.1/prod/x64/slack-desktop-4.26.1-amd64.deb
```

and then

```
sudo dpkg -i slack-desktop-4.26.1-amd64.deb
```

UPDATE:
I could have probably saved a lot of trouble by following [the dowgrade path](https://github.com/flatpak/flatpak/wiki/Tips-&-Tricks#downgrading) for flatpak apps.